# Unable to copy records from one table to another in Entity Framework MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have been trying to copy records from one table to another in Entity Framework MVC. Here is my code..

```
  var records = _db.Attendance.Get(e => attIdsToDelete.Contains(e.Id));
  _db.AttendanceHistory.Insert(records);
```

Now I have been getting the error on records that  "cannot convert from 'system.collections.generic.ienumerable' to 'attendancehistory'

The number of columns and type are both same in the database.

Comment: Have you want to save all records in the `IEnumerable`? Use a foreach loop and perform insert for every records stored in it.

Comment: the records contains the list of records (from Attendance table)  that I want to insert in the AttendanceHistory table... Now it throws error that I mentioned above.

Comment: How you are storing data from one table to another table without mapping tables or any forloop

Comment: Yes thank you so much, I didn't know how mapping is done but I figured it out at it is now working correctly...  I have made the following changes..
                var records = _db.AttendanceHistory.Get(e => attIdsToDelete.Contains(e.Id)).Select(a => new AttendanceHistory { Id= a.Id,EmployeeId= a.EmployeeId,AttendanceDate= a.AttendanceDate,DateIn= a.DateIn,TimeIn= a.TimeIn........});

Answer (score 0):

Please change this

```
_db.AttendanceHistory.Insert(records);
```

to this:

```
_db.AttendanceHistory.AddRange(records);
```

This should work if Attendance and AttendanceHistory are of the same type. If it still complains, try casting and changing to a list first:

```
 var records = _db.Attendance.Get(e => attIdsToDelete.Contains(e.Id)).ToList<AttendanceHistory>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method like below and copy all properties(values) from source class to destination class(if both class having same properties(name and datatype)

```
public class Utility
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy one class all properties to another class - if both the class having all the same properties
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="FromClass">Class A - from where properties need to be copied</param>
    /// <param name="ToClass">Class B - to whom properties need to be pasted</param>
    public static void CopyAllPropertiesFromOneClassToAnotherClass(object FromClass, object ToClass)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo propA in FromClass.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            PropertyInfo propB = ToClass.GetType().GetProperty(propA.Name);
            propB.SetValue(ToClass, propA.GetValue(FromClass, null), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can call to that method to copy the data like below

```
Utility.CopyAllPropertiesFromOneClassToAnotherClass(fromClassObject, toClassObject);
```